Is EXPOSE Only for Decoration?
TLDR: It seems that I forgot to EXPOSE Jenkins' ports, such as 8080 and 50000, but Jenkins still works and I'm able to access the WEB UI. How come?
So I've been learning Docker the past couple of months and while building Dockerfiles, I've always made sure to EXPOSE appropriate ports, 80 if I'm building a web app and so on.
I was building a Dockerfile that it's purpose is to run a Jenkins server within a container, with some applications that I need to make sure the pipelines run correctly.
It seems that I forgot to EXPOSE Jenkins' ports, such as 8080 and 50000, but Jenkins still works.
So this made me wonder, what's the actual usage of EXPOSE? I thought that without EXPOSE, the container doesn't open a port, hence making the application inside unavailable.
I understand that both the application and the container need to accept traffic on a specific port, as well as port mapping from a localhost to the container, i.e. the -port port:port flag.
How come my Dockerfile is working without EXPOSE stated within it? How am I able to access port 8080 inside the container, without the container port being exposed?
I essentially realized this once I changed some stuff in my Dockerfile, after the server was up and running as it should be.
I perhaps thought it might be because in Jenkins' case, the port is 8080, and it could be 2nd default to port 80? So the container by default accepts traffic to this port?

From the relevant documentation at docs.docker.com: "The EXPOSE instruction doesn't actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports."

In first-generation Docker networking it mattered – the accepted answer to the linked question is a decade old now – but today it is mostly-but-not-quite only for documentation.  In addition to the docker run -P flag, Docker Desktop knows to look for it.
